# ¿Cómo hacer una búsqueda en una base de datos en SQL Server y que el registro encontrado se muestre en un datagridview?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, sql-server-express

Mi cuestión es: tengo un sistema de punto de venta casi terminado, desarrollado en C# y con procedimientos almacenados (SQL Server), lo único que me gustaría saber como hacer es una consulta mediante el código y dicho registro encontrado me lo muestre en un DataGridView, para poder así poner solo un campo de "cantidad" y poder "vender" el o los productos. De antemano agradezco demasiado la ayuda.

sólo quiero darme una idea de mas o menos cómo sería el código, ya que tengo un apartado de búsqueda de "productos" pero digamos que en la programación del botón buscar me dirige a un formulario donde se filtran los productos buscados en un datagrid, una vez encontrado el producto, haces dobleclic y te lo pasa al formulario "principal" digamos y de ahi agrego el "producto", lo cual considero son demasiados pasos para el usuario final y quisiera simplificarlo, en resumidas cuentas, como se hace en una "tienda de conveniencia" o autoservicio , que pasás el artículo por el escaner o lector de código y dicho articulo se muestra en un datagrid. Espero haberme explicado un poco más y no haberme enredado, gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entiendo cual es tu problema particular. Tenes algun problema con el codigo? recibis algun error? podrias mostrarnos mas claramente que tratas de hacer?

Comment: Edité la pregunta, disculpa, a ver si fui un poco más claro, desde ya gracias!

Comment: El escaner o codigo de barras, no es mas que un teclado "camuflado".. funciona como si ingresaras los numeros con un teclado... Entonces sigo sin terminar de entender tu consulta

Answer (score 0):

Que el codigo del producto se ingrese manualmente en un textbox de busqueda o se lea desde un scaner de codigo de barras es exactamente lo mismo.

Puede usar

- el evento `LostFocus`del textbox
- el `KeyPress` detectando cuando se presiona `enter`
- el `click` de un boton para iniciar la busqueda

pero todos aportaran el codigo a la consulta que filtrara los datos y obtendra el producto que quieres llevar al grid.

Lo primero sera definir la entidad

```
public class Producto
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Codigo {get;set;}
    public int Descripcion {get;set;}
    public decimal Precio {get;set;}
}
```

Para luego recuperarla con una consulta

```
public Producto ObtenerPorCodigo(int codigo)  
{  
    Producto producto = null; 

    string connstring = "connection string";    
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring))  
    {    
        cn.Open();    

        string sql = @"SELECT Id, Codigo, Descripcion, Precio 
                        FROM Productos 
                        WHERE Codigo = @codigo";    
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);    
        cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@codigo", codigo);    

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();    

        if (reader.Read())    
        {    
            producto = new Producto();  
            item.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]);    
            item.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Codigo"]);   
            item.Descripcion = Convert.ToString(reader["Descripcion"]);         
            item.Precio = Convert.ToDEcimal(reader["Precio"]);    
        }    
    } 

    return producto;
}
```

Observaras como se usa el `codigo` que se pasa por parametro en el `WHERE` del `SELECT` para obtener solo ese registros que se vuelca a las propiedades de la entidad.

La respuesta de ese metodo lo usaras para generar el `Add()` del grid

Nota: alli no lo puse pero debes validar si se obtiene un `null` como respuesta al no encontrar un producto por el codigo que se ingresa

Answer (score 0):

Está muy bien lo que escribe Leandro. Sólo agregaría que, yo en lugar de usar un query de SQL plano y llano, llamé a un stored procedure desde C# de la siguiente manera:

```
public List<Producto> GetProducto(string nombre)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(helper.CnnVal("food")))
            {
                var output = connection.Query<Producto>("dbo.BuscarProducto @Nombre_prod", new { Nombre_prod = nombre }).ToList();
                return output;
            }
        }
```

Si te fijas hay una variable: "var output =". Explicar todo lo que sucede alrededor de ella llevaría demasiado tiempo, así que solo explicaré el query que tengo en ella (después te mando el link a donde yo saque el 80% de mi proyecto). Esa variable tiene un string `"dbo.BuscarProducto @Nombre_prod"` y ese string me conecta con un stored procedure que me hice:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BuscarProducto]

    @Nombre_prod VARCHAR (50)
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT * FROM Producto
WHERE Nombre_prod like '%'+@Nombre_prod+'%' or Descrip_Prod like '%'+@Nombre_prod+'%'
END
```

Este procedimiento está diciendo "vas a buscar un string (varchar en sql) que se llama @nombre de la siguiente manera: selecciona todo de la tabla Producto, donde el nombre del producto sea equivalente al string @nombre o bien, que la descripción del producto tambien sea equivalente a @nombre_prod". Ese like y esos % alrededor de @nombre lo que dicen es que no se va a buscar exactamente lo que dice @nombre_prod, sino que se va a buscar que cualquiera de las dos columnas contenga esa palabra o palabras.

Si yo hubiese escrito

```
SELECT * FROM Producto
WHERE Nombre_prod like '@Nombre_prod or Descrip_Prod like @Nombre_prod
```

entonces el sistema me hubiera buscado ese contenido exacto y no me daría resultados aún cuando en la descripción del producto tuviese un pedacito en el que concuerda con la búsqueda.

Y, ¿quién decide que contiene @nombre? Pues, el usuario que abra su barra de búsqueda y escriba aquello que desee buscar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, el sistema le va a ofrecer los resultados disponibles en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como notarás, yo no uso un DataGridView, sino que uso un DataList, sin embargo, junto con el ListBox, usan propiedades muy similares:

```
        listaencontrados.DataSource = producto;
        listaencontrados.DataTextField = "fullinfo";
        listaencontrados.DataBind();
        DataProducto.DataSource = producto;
        DataProducto.DataMember = "Nombre_prod";
        DataProducto.DataMember = "Descrip_prod";
        DataProducto.DataMember = "Precio_Unit";
        DataProducto.DataMember = "Img_origen";
        DataProducto.DataBind();
```

ListaEncontrados es un ListBox, DataProducto es un DataList, sólo que en DataProducto hice que me diera cada campo por separado, mientras que en el ListBox concatené todo. En WindowsForms es un poquito diferente, pero no es la gran cosa. El vídeo que te mandaré explica que propiedades usarás.

En fin, eso sería una pequeña introducción a lo que estoy haciendo. Hace poco hice una pregunta similar, nadie respondió. Sin embargo, me dí a la tarea de buscar y logré esto. Lo estoy haciendo en ASP.NET WebForms y son mínimas las cosas que cambian en comparación con WindowsForms. De hecho, mi fuente lo hace en WindowsForms:

[How to connect C# to SQL (the easy way)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Et2khGnrIqc)

Lo único "malo" es que está en inglés, pero te recomiendo demasiado aprenderlo, no solo porque hay muchísima info de programación en inglés, sino porque también vas a entender el significado de las palabras usadas en el lenguaje de programación y entender la lógica se te hará un poco mas fácil.

Espero que te sea de ayuda mi granito de arena. Sólo recuerda que la lógica que cada quien tiene es única, así como las necesidades de tu proyecto. No todo lo que te encuentres o te aconsejen va a ser 100% aplicable. Toma lo más útil.

Comment: venga bro, ahora lo checo y te cuento como me fue , gracias!